# Is $x=0$ if $|x|<\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ ??

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x$ be a real number. If $|x|< \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, then $x=0$. That was a lemma in my lecture today. My Dr. proceeded as follows:

- Suppose that $x≠0$
- Choose $\varepsilon =|x|/2>0$
- We have $|x|<|x|/2$  (*according to our assumption*)
- Which is a **contradiction**
- Thus $x=0$

But I have a little question here:

- If I took $\varepsilon=1>0$
- I have $|x|<1$
- Then $-1<x<1$
- Thus we can't assure the value $x=0$, it has more values, since $x$ is a real number in the interval $]-1,1[$

  Is my Dr.'s solution accurate or am I missing something?

Comment: *Any* means *every* in that context.

Comment: If you believe that there can be other $x$ values, you can say it. For example, does $x= \frac 13$ work? No, because it would fail for $\varepsilon = \frac 14$. In fact, any $x \neq 0$ fails.

Comment: @ThePortakal Do you mean that if I chose a value for x≠0 I am still able to find a value for ε such that |x|>ε because ε can be any value?

Comment: I think I'm getting it right here. I have a problem with Quantifiers. Is there a way to facilitate their concepts?

Comment: Consider using LaTeX symbols instead of cut-and-pasting. The command \varepsilon between dollar signs will give you $\varepsilon$, e.g. 0 < \varepsilon \ll 1 will give $0 < \varepsilon \ll 1$. If you prefer $\epsilon$, then just use \epsilon instead.

Comment: Thank you @FlybyNight